# Scala standalone object not getting recognized

Tags: scala, class, object

I am creating a singleton object using script xyz.scala as follow :

```
object ChecksumCalculator {
                 def calcChecksum(s: String): Int = {
                   val cc = new ChecksumCalculator
                   for (c <- s)
                     cc.add(c.toByte)
                   cc.checksum
} }
```

When I run this as script as `Scala xyz.scala` ,

I am getting the error as :

```
01HW993798:scala tcssig$ scalac xyz.scala
xyz.scala:3: error: not found: type ChecksumCalculator
                   val cc = new ChecksumCalculator
                                ^
one error found
```

Although I have declared the standalone object at the top, is it possible that my standalone object is not getting recognized.

Or is it due to some other error ?

Comment: Scala objects cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Are you missing a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scala, singleton objects are instantiated on usage and guaranteed to be instantiated only once, hence providing strict "singleton" semantics.

Assuming that your object has method "add(b:Byte)" you could do:

```
CheckSumCalculator.add(c.toByte)
```

But given that we are in the scope of `CheckSumCalculator`, using this should be sufficient:

```
add(c.toByte)
```

---

That said, using a singleton object for mutable operations seems a bad idea.

It looks like that what you are looking for is to create instances of some class, but also have some facility method that can be called statically.

That construction has a name in Scala: A [***companion object***](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html)

*companion objects* are defined by creating an object of the same name as some given class.

Translating that to this scenario, we would have:

```
class ChecksumCalculator {
  def add(b:Byte) = ???
  def checksum(): Int = ??? // or whatever type the checksum is
}
object ChecksumCalculator {  // this is a companion object
  def calcChecksum(s: String): Int = {
    val cc = new ChecksumCalculator
    s.foreach(c => cc.add(c.toByte))
    cc.checksum()
  }
}
```

Comment: It is getting instantiated only once in my code, where `val cc` is being created. Is there an error in initializing `val cc`

Comment: @Sarang in Scala you don't instantiate an object. Once declared it can be used as explained. If you want an instance, you need a `class`.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But what shud replace `val cc = new ChecksumCalculator` in my code ?

Comment: @Sarang.  Not needed. You should remove it. Assuming that you keep the `object` implementation, then you could refer to the methods in your object like this: `ChecksumCalculator.add(...)`, `ChecksumCalculator.foo(...)`. Again, a singleton object does not seem the right choice in this case. If I were you, I would consider implementing the functionality as a `class`

Comment: @Sarang I think I understood the "root" of your question. See the edit above.